# Scheduling Queue for First Come First Server Algorithm

Tags: operating-system, scheduling, task-queue, round-robin

[image]

I have the above table, and i have to make a **gantt chart** for **first come first server (FCFS)** and **Round-Robin (RR)** algorithms, also something called a **wait queue** which i really don't know what it is, after googling a bit i think it's the Queue that has the process that will be executed next? now for FCFS i came up with this charts

[image]

yellow means it's executing, green it's waiting for its turn (in READY state), red means it's doing I/O, my question is this correct? if so, what would be the **waiting queue** be ? i'm thinking it will be `P3, P1, P3, P1, P0` (in from right, out from left) which is just the processes sorted based on yellow in reverse. Or should it be the blue stuff ? since the process is in WAIT state there ?

[image]

i Also have to make a `Wait time` and `response time` table, for:

`response time = start time - arrival time`

`wait time = time where the process is not in RUNNING state`, ie it's in WAIT, thus i counted the green blue time since the process started executing

i'm pretty sure that `response time is correct, i'm doubting the latter

Last thing is: **at the end of a quantum, the current running process is suspended (interrupted) if and only if the process queue is not empty**, since statement has the word **quantum** i'm assuming it's only valid for **Round-Robin** scheduling? if so, please elaborate on what this means? i made sense of it like: if **quantum** time passes, the current running process will be interrupted if and only if there's another process waiting to be executed (ie if we only have one process, and say it runs for 6 units of time, and `quantum=3`, there's no need to run it for 3 units of time, then make it wait another 3 units of time, then run it again, so the proper answer would be: the process runs from t=0 to t=6 non-stop)